# Downloading image from Firebase and adding it to an Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Basically what I got so far is an Array which includes every data that is necessary for my prototyp cell. I retrieve that data (image, name and brand) from Firebase. Now, I created a loop to retrieve everything from the Database, but my problem now, is that I cant add the "image" to my "tempShopCells.append()" method, because it is inside that loop and not reachable.
The code:

```
func createArray(completion: @escaping ([ShopCell]) -> () ) {
    var tempShopCells: [ShopCell] = []
    let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    let query = rootRef.child("tobacco").queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let value = child.value as? [String: Any];
            let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? "";
            let brand = value?["brand"] as? String ?? "";
            let iD = value?["iD"] as? String ?? "";
            let imageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("tobaccoPictures").child("\(iD).jpg")
            imageReference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
                if let _error = error{
                    print(_error)
                } else {
                    if let _data  = data {
                        let image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
                    }
                }
            }
            tempShopCells.append(ShopCell(productName: name, brandName: brand, productImage: image))
        }
        completion(tempShopCells)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move line where you apppending new element to array right after initializing image from `_data`

```
if let _data = data {
     let image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
     tempShopCells.append(ShopCell(productName: name, brandName: brand, productImage: image))
}
```

also note that retrieving images' datas are asynchronous tasks, so completion's data will be empty array.

So I would recommend you using `DispatchGroup`.

First create new `DispatchGroup`. Then before you ask for image's data, *enter* to `dispatchGroup` and after you receive data *leave* `dispatchGroup`. When every image's data is received, call `completion` in closure of `dispatchGroup.notify(queue:)`

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    ...
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    imageReference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
        ... // error, appending to array, etc.
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }    
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    completion(tempShopCells)
}
```

Comment: And what to do now, because the Array is empty? In fact I wrote createArray() { shopCells in
            for item in shopCells {
                self.ShopCells.append(item)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView_shop.reloadData()
            }
        } in viewDidLoad() function... But that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Should I write the "dispatchGroup.leave()" inside the "if let data" or outside of the whole if else statement?

Comment: @FlorianLee outside the whole if else statement

Comment: Everything is working like it should now! Thanks a lot!